# Dynamically change div content with lat and lng

Tags: jquery

I have a page url. For example my page url is

```
www.abc.com/index.php?lat=68&lng=62
```

Here is 68 and 62 values of the variables. I store this values in two div.

```
var lat=$("#lat").val();
var lng=$("#lng").val();
```

I write this values two div.

```
$("#a").text(lat);
$("#b").text(lng);
```

When I change 68 and 62 values on the url. How can I update dynamically div #a and div #b content?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using JQuery Get method?

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/how-to-get-querystring-value-using.html